# how to send same OTP to mobile number and Email with firebase

Tags: swift, iosdeployment

when I'm tried to send firebase otp to mail I got string formed

```
func sendOtpToMobile() {
  guard let phonenumber = phoneNumberTextField.text else { return }
  PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phonenumber, uiDelegate: nil) { [self] (verificationID , error) in
    if error == nil {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "verificationID")
      UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    } else {
      print("unable to get verification code" , error?.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.